# The exact syntax to get nested attribute from Json response with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I receive from server a response in this form

```
{"error":null,"id":1,"result":{"admin":false,"firstname":"Jason","id":346,"idHotel":109,"idVendor":null,"lastname":"Butcher","sessionkey":"3c8a17ae47a6d131b1a14b44a1d8f9a9","urlAvatar":"avatar_316_mjm.jpg","urlThumb":"thumb_316_mjm.jpg"}}
```

And want to get the various singles attributes, in the nested json result as primitive

for example

```
Boolean error=..;
String admin=....;
String idHotel=...;
```

I have tried to make a class in this way

```
public class HotelLogin {
    public boolean error;
    public int id;
    public Result result;
    //get and set


    public static class Result {
       public String lastname;

       ...
       ...//get and set
    }
}
```

and I have used this code tying to deserialize the JSONObject *serverResponse*

```
HotelLogin loggedRs= new HotelLogin();
Gson gson = new Gson();
response = gson.fromJson(serverResponse, HotelLogin.class);
```

But at this point I don't know how to get the single attributes of the inner json.

And if I use the code

```
Result user=login.getResult();
String lastname=user.getLastname();
```

Get a null pointer exception

Answer (score -1):

Well, assuming that you have a variable or a return data which contains your server response, you can try this:

```
var newError = data.Error;
var newId    = data.Id;
var newFirstName = data.result.firstname;
```

OR

```
var serverResponse = data; //(considering that this 'data' is your json object);

//you access it through dot notation.

serverResponse.error;
serverResponse.result.admin;
serverResponse.result.id;
```

Each one will get your required data. You can loop through your json object, if your prefer, but i like to use dot notation. Note that you can't always use it, since you **must** know if a attribute has a child node.

Comment: The question is how to do this with Java, not JavaScript